# weak convergence implies point-wise convergence?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, measure-theory, convergence-divergence, weak-convergence

If we have a bounded sequence $\{f_n\} \in L^p[a,b]$ that converges weakly to $f$ does this mean that the converges is also pointwise??

thank you.

Answer (score 6):

No. Just take $f_n\in L^2[0,1]$, $f_n = \sin(n\pi x)$. Then $f_n\rightharpoonup0$ in $L^2[0,1]$.